# Why I have result in scientific notation

Tags: spring-boot, log4j

Why I have result in scientific notation

I would like to log time generated as output of method in seconds I do it like below

```
logger.info("JPA   "+ numberOfTest +"X test findProductByProductName               "+ (double) timeCounter.avarageTimeJPAFindProductByProductName(numberOfTest,"Chai")/1000000000.0d);
logger.info("JDBC  "+ numberOfTest +"X test findProductByProductName               "+ (double) timeCounter.avarageTimeJDBCFindProductByProductName(numberOfTest,"Chai")/1000000000.0d);
```

But in output, I can see result in scientific notation only for `timeCounter.avarageTimeJDBCFindProductByProductName(numberOfTest,"Chai")/1000000000.0d` ?

[image]

I do not know why? Can You provide me optimal way to log time in given format, for example in seconds? I used for logging org.apache.log4j.Logger;

Comment: What is the result of timeCounter.avarageTimeJDBCFindProductByProductName. In what unit is the result?

Comment: method timeCounter.avarageTimeJDBCFindProductByProductName returns the result as Double `return Arrays.stream(time).average().getAsDouble();`